# Ubuntu shows an icon for root

Tags: partitioning, root, 21.04

I have upgraded to 21.04 from 20.10 and after the upgrade for some reason Ubuntu shows a icon on desktop of the / folder which I am unable to remove. Also when this happens it doesn't show the other partitions of Windows eventhough I have disabled fast boot.
Here is a screenshot:

[image]

If you need further info by running a command please let me know.